# Python picamera.split_recording occasionally dropping frames between splits

Tags: python, video, camera, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Sample footage of what I'm talking about, the first one happens about 6 seconds in: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxTM42pAGYw

My code: https://github.com/nicolashahn/pi-helmet-cam/blob/master/camera.py

It seems to be dropping about a second or two of footage between splits, but it doesn't happen often, though enough that it happens several times in that clip. Is there any way around this? What's causing it?

Comment: I think your camera irecording is blocked by the IO-operation. Can you try to do the IO in a separate thread?

Comment: Can you extrapolate on this? Not sure how to go about doing that

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently doing is:

1. Capturing a new image
2. Storing it onto a harddisk / sdcard

And you are doing this in one single thread. 
So what could happen:
The IO-operation to write your image onto your hd / sdcard takes more time than your timeframe between two images. Special sd-cards are not as fast as ssd-hd for instance ( you are normally using sd-cards on a raspberry ).

What can you do to get around this: write your data into a network stream and store the data on a pc. How to do this can be found here: https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes1.html#capturing-to-a-network-stream

Or you can try to do the store-step in a separate thread. But I am not sure if this will solve your issue, because the performance of the sdcard will be the same.

Comment: Store the data on a PC? I'm using this for a helmet cam, so I won't be connected to anything while recording.

Comment: Then you need to connect some kind of ssd to it. Or store it on an usbstick, if its faster. Try it out.

Comment: This is less than ideal, it will add a lot of bulk to the overall package and will the ssd really be faster over usb than a class 10 SD card? And is the issue that I need two places for storage because picamera temporarily writes to SD during filming and then does another write at the split?

Comment: Of course you can also try to use a compression for your images.